# Python: argparse subcommand subcommand?

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I have a program that has many available options.
For example a configuration option to change settings.

```
./app config -h
```

gives me the help using normal argparse subcommands

now i would like to add another subcommand to the config subcommand called list to list config values

```
./app config list
```

additionally that command should accept another option so that i could say

```
./app config list CATEGORY
```

only to list the config of one category

my code right now is basically this just with more commands

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title='subcommands',
...                                    description='valid subcommands',
...                                    help='additional help')
>>> subparsers.add_parser('foo')
>>> subparsers.add_parser('bar')
>>> parser.parse_args(['-h'])
usage:  [-h] {foo,bar} ...

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

subcommands:
  valid subcommands

  {foo,bar}   additional help
```

So far I could not find any way to use a subcommand in a subcommand.
If this is possible, how? If not, is there any other way to accomplish this goal?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It would be better if you post your code here, to help others understanding your problem.

Comment: I recommend people look at the click library https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/quickstart/#nesting-commands

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#file: argp.py

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser_subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
sub = parser_subparsers.add_parser('sub')
sub_subparsers = sub.add_subparsers()
sub_sub = sub_subparsers.add_parser('sub_sub')                                                                       
sub_sub_subparsers = sub_sub.add_subparsers()
sub_sub_sub = sub_sub_subparsers.add_parser('sub_sub_sub')
```

Seems to work.

```
In [392]: run argp.py

In [393]: parser.parse_args('sub sub_sub sub_sub_sub'.split())
Out[393]: Namespace()

In [400]: sys.version_info
Out[400]: sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Comment: I tried with 2.7.2 I'd certainly like to know if you have issues :)