# Subcommand alternative to argparse and optparse

Tags: python, argparse, optparse

Is there any intuitive alternative for argparse/optparse for subcommands? They both are bad - it is either insane config or insane output.

Real world example ([stolen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368110/python-argparse-subcommand-subcommand), not wanted):

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title='subcommands',
...                                    description='valid subcommands',
...                                    help='additional help')
>>> subparsers.add_parser('foo')
>>> subparsers.add_parser('bar')
>>> parser.parse_args(['-h'])
usage:  [-h] {foo,bar} ...

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

subcommands:
  valid subcommands

  {foo,bar}   additional help
```

Wanted:

```
>>> parser = cmdline.Parser(
...   tplheader='Usage: tool [command] [options]',
...   tplcommandhead='Available commands:',
...   tplfooter='Use \"tool help\" to get full list of supported commands.')
>>> parser.add('foo', help='foo.')
>>> parser.add('bar', help='bar.')
>>> parser.parse(['-h'])
Usage: tool [command] [options]
Available commands:

  foo        foo.
  bar        bar.

Use "tool help" to get full list of supported commands.
```

**UPDATE**: I would accept the answer that provides command validation and parsing example that gives the help message exactly as the last snippet.

Comment: 'output' - do mean the help message, or the object with the parsed values?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Click](http://click.pocoo.org/). See the documentation on [commands and groups](http://click.pocoo.org/3/commands/) for details for details about subcommands.

Comment: @hpaulj, `output` is the help message. Fixed description.

Answer (score 9):

You can get pretty close to your requested output just by changing your argparse code a little bit:

1. Set the usage text by specifying the `usage` parameter to `ArgumentParser`.
2. Omit the `description` and `help` arguments to `add_subparsers`.
3. Change the `title` parameter to `Available subcommands`.
4. Use the `metavar` parameter to override the unsightly `{foo,bar}` text.
5. Use the `help` arguments available in `add_parser`.

Here's the finished product:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage='tool [command] [options]')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title='Available commands', metavar='')
subparsers.add_parser('foo', help='foo.')
subparsers.add_parser('bar', help='bar.')
parser.parse_args(['-h'])
```

That code prints this:

```
usage: tool [command] [options]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

Available commands:

    foo       foo.
    bar       bar.
```

Comment: Add an 'epilog' and 'add_help=False' and you will get even closer.   I was over thinking the problem with my answer.

Comment: I intentionally omitted the epilogue text because it will take additional work to make the requested text be an accurate description of the behavior, @Hpaulj. Existing commands seem split on whether the help is accessed by a dedicated subcommand or by an option, and the option method is already built in to the argparse library.

Comment: @RobKennedy, nice try. It could be a good answer to illustrate why `argparse` can not do the job. It looks almost ok, but I suspect that getting the desired output exactly as requested is not easy.

Comment: @hpaulj, it shows `optional arguments` garbage and no footer is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for [`argh`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argh).

Here's a snippet from the presentation on the home page.

> A potentially modular application with multiple commands:

```
import argh

# declaring:

def echo(text):
    "Returns given word as is."
    return text

def greet(name, greeting='Hello'):
    "Greets the user with given name. The greeting is customizable."
    return greeting + ', ' + name

# assembling:

parser = argh.ArghParser()
parser.add_commands([echo, greet])

# dispatching:

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser.dispatch()
```

> Of course it works:

```
$ ./app.py greet Andy
Hello, Andy

$ ./app.py greet Andy -g Arrrgh
Arrrgh, Andy
```

The help message on the site is slightly abridged.  Here is what it actually outputs for me (`argh` 0.26.1).

```
$ ./app.py --help
usage: app.py [-h] {greet,echo} ...

positional arguments:
  {greet,echo}
    echo        Returns given word as is.
    greet       Greets the user with given name. The greeting is customizable.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help    show this help message and exit
```

Comment: What about `./app.py -h`?

Comment: Updated answer with a copy from the site, but really, check the link for the rest.

Comment: What it _says_ on the tin is totally unhelpful. What it _does_ is much better though.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plac is another parser built on top of `argparse`.  You define 'commands' by specifying functions that will be invoked.  It uses the function parameters to populate the parser arguments.

Comment: @tripleee, does it allow to  change `positional arguments:` line?  Also `svn help` is about 10+ commands. Will they all be stacked in usage line?

Comment: @tripleee, your example of auto-generated help is different from what your snippet produces with latest `argh 0.26.1` and python 2/3.  =/

Comment: The page does mention that the example is somewhat simplified. I'll update the answer to clarify this.

Comment: @tripleee, downvoted, because the output is forged and doesn't reflect the reality.

Comment: Seriously!? Okay, updated with precisely the output I get when I install 0.26.1 here.

Answer (score 1):

Does this win the prize?  :)

### Custom parameters

Rob Kennedy has a better customization.

```
In [158]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(usage='tool [command] [options]',
  description= "Available commands:\n\n   foo    foo.\n   bar    bar.\n",
  epilog= 'Use "tool help" to get full list of supported commands',
  formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter, add_help=False)

In [159]: parser.print_help()
usage: tool [command] [options]

Available commands:

   foo    foo.
   bar    bar.

Use "tool help" to get full list of supported commands
```

What I've done is customize the `help` with available parameters.

### Alternative API and/or parser?

But your other lines, the `parse.add()` ones suggest you don't like the `argparse` method of defining 'commands'.  You could add some methods to your parser that use this more compact syntax, but still end up calling the existing `subparser` mechanism.

But maybe you want to replace the whole parsing scheme with your own.  One, for example, that expects the first argument to be a 'command'.  What about other 'positionals'?  Who or what handles the 'options'?

Do you realize that the `argparse` subparser scheme is built on top of the more basic `optionals` and `positionals` parsing scheme.  The `parser.add_subparsers` command is a specialized form of `add_argument`.  The `subparsers` object is a positional argument, with a special Action class.  `{foo,bar}` is actually a list of the `choices` values that you defined for this argument (names or aliases of the subcommands).  The subcommands themselves are parsers.

### Custom front end command parser

If the `sys.argv[1]` item will always be a `command` name, you could set up something like this:

```
if sys.argv[1:]:
    cmd = sys.argv[1]
    rest = sys.argv[2:]
    parser = parser_dict.get(cmd, None)
    if parser:
        args = parser.parse_args(rest)
else:
    print_default_help()
```

Where `parser_dict` is a dictionary matching `cmd` strings to defined parsers.  In effect this is just a front end that captures the first argument string, and dispatches the handling of the rest to other defined parsers.  They could be a mix of `argparse`, `optparse`, and custom parsers.  This front end does not have to be fancy if all it handles is the first 'command' string.

`print_default_help` would be little more than a pretty print of the `parser_dict`.

On further thought, I realized that the `sp.choices` attribute of an `argparse` subparsers object is just such a dictionary - with command strings as keys, and parsers as values.

### Custom format_help methods

Here are a couple of custom help formatters.

A simple one that only gets the `prog` and `_choices_actions` from the `parser`.  `subparsers._choices_actions` is a list of objects that contain help and aliases information for the individual sub parsers.

```
def simple_help(parser, subparsers):
    # format a help message with just the subparser choices
    usage = "Usage: %s command [options]"%parser.prog
    desc = "Available commands:\n"
    epilog = '\nUse "%s help" to get full list of supported commands.'%parser.prog
    choices = fmt_choices(subparsers._choices_actions)
    astr = [usage]
    astr.append(desc)
    astr.extend(choices)
    astr.append(epilog)
    return '\n'.join(astr)

def fmt_choices(choices):
    # format names and help in 2 columns
    x = max(len(k.metavar) for k in choices)
    fmt = '   {:<%s}   {}'%x
    astr = []
    for k in choices:
        # k.metavar lists aliases as well
        astr.append(fmt.format(k.dest, k.help))
    return astr
```

This one is modeled on `parser.format_help`, and makes uses of the `Formatter` and all of its wrapping and spacing information.  I wrote it to use non-default parameters where possible.  It is hard, though, to suppress blank lines.

```
def special_help(parser, subparsers=None, usage=None, epilog=None):
    # format help message using a Formatter
    # modeled on parser.format_help
    # uses nondefault parameters where possible
    if usage is None:
        usage = "%(prog)s command [options]"
    if epilog is None:
        epilog = "Use '%(prog)s help' for command list"
    if subparsers is None:
        # find the subparsers action in the parser
        for action in parser._subparsers._group_actions:
            if hasattr(action, '_get_subactions'):
                subparsers = action
                break
        # if none found, subparsers is still None?
    if parser._subparsers != parser._positionals:
        title = parser._subparsers.title
        desc = parser._subparsers.description
    else:
        title = "Available commands"
        desc = None
    if subparsers.metavar is None:
        subparsers.metavar = '_________'
        # restore to None at end?
    formatter = parser._get_formatter()
    if parser.usage is None:
        formatter.add_usage(usage, [], [])
    else:
        formatter.add_usage(parser.usage,
            parser._actions, parser._mutually_exclusive_groups)
    # can I get rid of blank line here?
    formatter.start_section(title)
    formatter.add_text(desc)
    formatter.add_arguments([subparsers])
    formatter.end_section()
    formatter.add_text(epilog)
    return formatter.format_help()
```

These could be invoked in different ways.  Either could replace the `parser's` `format_help` method, and thus be produced by the `-h` option, as well as with `parser.print_help()`.

Or you could include a `help` subcommand.  This would fit with the `epilog` message.  `-h` would still produce the full, ugly help.

```
sp3 = sp.add_parser('help')  # help='optional help message'
```

and test `args`:

```
if args.cmd in ['help']:
    print(simple_help(parser, sp))
    # print(special_help(parser))
```

Another option is to check `sys.argv` before `parser.parser_args`, and call the help function if that list isn't long enough, or includes a `help` string.  This is roughly what `Ipython` does to bypass the regular `argparse` help.

Comment: I probably could hack argparser by copy pasting multiple pages of class definitions, but I'd rather use a library that is short and intuitive and doesn't overburden my command line helpers.

Comment: Normally the `argparse` help formatter is tweaked by changing just a few methods of the formatter class.  Obviously you do have to study the code enough to know where to make those few changes.  No one is going to hand you a custom formatter on a platter.

Comment: that's why this question is about alternatives to `argparse` where writing custom formatter is as easy as in my question and doesn't require you a days of debate to get the exact output right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand what's wrong with what you describe.
I use something slightly different though:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My description')
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', type=str, required=True, help='Inputfile')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', type=str, required=False, help='Output file')
args = parser.parse_args()
input_filename = args.input
if not args.output:
    output_filename = input_filename
else:
    output_filename = args.output
```

Comment: You don't use subcommands at all. Try to exec `hg` or `svn help` output to see the difference.

Comment: Oh now I see what you mean. Good idea, I'll start using those too.. once you get a good answer to your question :-)

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/5.x/why/). From the documentation, Click...

- is lazily composable without restrictions
- fully follows the Unix command line conventions
- supports loading values from environment variables out of the box
- supports for prompting of custom values
- is fully nestable and composable
- works the same in Python 2 and 3
- supports file handling out of the box
- comes with useful common helpers (getting terminal dimensions, ANSI colors, fetching direct keyboard input, screen clearing, finding config paths, launching apps and editors, etc.)

Arguments and options are pretty intuitive to create with decorators. You can create subcommands by creating groups as shown below.

```
import click                                                    


@click.command()                                                
@click.option('--count', default=1, help='number of greetings') 
@click.argument('name')                                         
def hello(count, name):                                         
    for i in range(count):                                      
        print(f"{i}. Hello {name}")                             

@click.group()                                                  
def cli():                                                      
    pass                                                        

@cli.command()                                                  
def initdb():                                                   
    click.echo('Initialized the database')                      

@cli.command()                                                  
def dropdb():                                                   
    click.echo('Dropped the database')                          

if __name__ == "__main__":                                      
    cli()
```

The output from this code is:

```
$ python click-example.py --help
Usage: click-example.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  dropdb
  initdb
```