# Make instance methods global in module?

Tags: python

I create a lib which can be imported and used as is, and there is also a start script, which creates a single instance of the main class for use within the script:

```
# read config, init stuff, and then create an instance

r = RepoClient(config)
```

Now, the start script accepts a 'command' argument, and as of now, it must be invoke like:

```
repo config.json -c 'r.ls()'
```

i.e.  the 'r' variable must be used.

I would like to be able to drop the 'r' variable. For that, the start script, somehow, needs the `ls` function. I can do it by putting the following in the script, after the `r` instance is created:

```
ls = r.ls
```

etc. for all the commands the RepoClient class supports.

Is there anything automatic? The code below doesn't work, of course, but you get the idea:

```
from r import *
```

What I can think of is annotating methods with a custom `@command` annotation, iterating over all the methods and checking for it and if found, setting it as a script global, but hopefully the batteries do support something like this already ;d

**EDIT:** for now, the command passed as the last argument is run the following way:

```
exec(sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: why not:
```def ls(*args, **kargs):  return r.ls(*args, **kargs)```?

Comment: Because I have to write all that code. And it is exactly the same as `ls = r.ls` (at least I think so, I'm not a Python pro). The `r` instance has quite a few commands similar to `ls`, and I would have to perform such an assignment for each one. Then, if I add a new command/method, I have to remember to add it to the script globals as well - error prone stuff, which should be automized.

Comment: Do you really need the command string you pass to your script to be the same as what names are looked up the module namespace?  I think you could make it so `ls()` just looks the names up in the instance namespace, rather than copying the instance namespace into the module namespace.

Comment: @wujek ah, ok. I believe that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268643/package-specific-import-hooks-in-python can be helpful

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to *achieve*, out of context; I suspect an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731).

Comment: @BrenBarn How can I do that? Just to be clear, `ls` is a method of `RepoClient`, as is `mkdir`, `find`, `cd` etc. The script invocation could be: `repo config.json 'r.find("test/bla")`, `ls` is just a basic example.

Comment: I think you want argparse subcommands. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368110/python-argparse-subcommand-subcommand

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think the question is pretty clear: I'm asking how to 'copy' all methods from an instance to the global namespace of the script r is defined in, so that I can omit the `r.` part. I can do this in other languages, like for example Groovy, and the result is a nice DSL.

Comment: @wujek then use Groovy! Without an explanation of what you are actually trying to do, it's hard to make sensible suggestions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, but what is not clear? I want to be able to pass the command `ls()` to the script instead of `r.ls()`, i.e. I somehow want to get rid of the `r`. I know I can manually copy the functions to the globals in the script; I know I can use argparse etc I' asking wthether Python supports something like `from r import *` to just copy all the methods to the global scope, like is possible for modules. 'Use Groovy' is not a solution as it has to be Python, period.

Comment: @wujek: You'd need to show *how* your start script is taking that command string and running it.

Comment: *"I' asking wthether [sic] Python supports something like `from r import *` to just copy all the methods to the global scope"* - then the answer is no, you can't import the methods out of an instance.

Comment: @BrenBarn Done in an edit (it's just an exec() call).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I know that this syntax does't work. Is there anything else I could try, or is my idea of iterating over the methods and just copying them into the global space the way to do it? Just for information: in Groovy I would implement the `def getProperty(...)` method, which is invoked for any missing property of the instance it is defined in (scripts are Script instances), and it could look it up in the `r` instance. Does Python have something along these lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that "automatically".  However, you don't actually need to copy the items into the global namespace.  You can pass a namespace to `exec` to use.  You could give your `RepoClient` a `__getitem__` method, allowing it to act as a namespace.  Here's a simple example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def blah(self):
        print("Blah!")

    def __getitem__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self, attr)

f = Foo()

exec('blah()', globals(), f)
```

It outputs `Blah!`.

Comment: This is good. I can even define the `__getitem__` method in the script and add it to the Foo class by `Foo.__getitem__ = lambda self, name: getattr(self, name)` and it still works.